# Build error with Visual Studio online

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I develop an ASP.NET MVC Code First Application which I host on Azure.

I tried to enable the Continous Integration Flow described here. ->http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso-git/

Meaning: I have a Visual Studio online account and use GIT as my repository. So the CI Flow should be: Check in something to my git, make a build, deploy the build to my testing env.

But I keep getting build errors when I check in my code to GIT. When compiling the code locally it is working fine and I can deploy manually without problems to AZURE. I have added the build error message I currently receive if I build via Visual Studio online

Any ideas?

Error message:

```
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets (55): Web deployment task failed. (Cannot connect to the database 'BookwellDB'.  Learn more at: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.)

Cannot connect to the database 'BookwellDB'.  Learn more at: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.
Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=BookwellDB;integrated security=True' cannot be created.
Failed to connect to server .
Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=35606; handshake=191; 
The wait operation timed out
  Learn more at: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
Failed to connect to server .
Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=35606; handshake=191; 
The wait operation timed out`
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, you need to add more information about the project if you want help. What kind of solution are you trying to build?

Comment: Hi Mark, I added some more information. I want to build my ASP.NET MVC Website via Visual Studio Online

Comment: The error appears to be when the build attempts to use MSDeploy to publish your website. I have never been over fond on deploying from the build but there is some quality tooling out there to do it. Are you deploying to a WebSite or a VM?

Comment: I am deploying to a Website....according to my build log it is failing here Run MSBuild
ProcessPublishDatabaseSettings:
  Creating directory "obj\Debug\Database".
  Starting Web deployment task from source: DbFullSql(******) to Destination: DbFullSql(******). So I assume this is because it is somehow trying to deploy my local DB, but of course I would like to have it using my Azure DB

Comment: Yes, you will need to figure out how to convert your local db to an Azure DB. Also note an Azure DB is tied down by IP address ranges. Your build server may not be in that ip range and since you are using a hosted build server, that can be a problem. A VSO web hook may solve your issue. I am about to tackle a similar problem in the next 2 days, if you have not solved this by then, I will post my solution.

Comment: Ok..but my build server is the hosted one from Visual Studio online. I understood the Build Server within Visual Studio Online is taking my GIT checkin and compiling it. Then it is pushing it onto my AZURE website I have configured in my Build Definition. I already have a DB in place and also think I pass the .pubxml file within my build definition on the right spot. (property MSBuildArgument in the BuildDefinition)